# value of a variable randomly changing from 2 to -1 in a when loop

Tags: kotlin

Beginner question but any idea why my *lemonsSize* is changing when switching between *lemonadeState*? Any help is greatly appreciated :)

The app/code is part of intro to Kotlin course by Google which is for creating a lemonade app that rotates between screens
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-project-lemonade?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-four%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-training-project-lemonade#0

**Below is where I think the problem is:**

```
when (lemonadeState) {
    SELECT -> {

        Log.d(TAG, "lemonadeState at beginning of SELECT *should be SELECT* lemonadeState = $lemonadeState")


        // Set the lemonSize (the number of squeezes needed) by calling the pick() method
        //val lemonSize = LemonTree()//UPDATE

        //Temp set lemonSize to 2 and log lemonSize value
        val lemonSize = 2
        Log.d(TAG, " setting lemonSize to 2 -> lemonSize = $lemonSize")


        // Setting the squeezeCount (the number of times the user has squeezed the lemon) to 0.
        squeezeCount = 0
        Log.d(TAG, " setting squeezeCount to 0 -> squeezeCount = $squeezeCount")

        // Transition to the SQUEEZE state
        lemonadeState = SQUEEZE
        Log.d(TAG, "lemonadeState at bottom of SELECT *should be SQUEEZE* lemonadeState = $lemonadeState")
    }


    // TODO: When the image is clicked in the SQUEEZE state the squeezeCount needs to be
    //  INCREASED by 1 and lemonSize needs to be DECREASED by 1.
    //  - If the lemonSize has reached 0, it has been juiced and the state should become DRINK
    //  - Additionally, lemonSize is no longer relevant and should be set to -1
    SQUEEZE -> {
        Log.d(TAG, "at top of SQUEEZE *lemonSize should be 2* lemonSize = $lemonSize")
        Log.d(TAG, "at top of SQUEEZE *lemonadeState should be SQUEEZE* lemonadeState = $lemonadeState")

        //squeezeCount needs to be INCREASED by 1
        squeezeCount += 1

        //lemonSize needs to be DECREASED by 1.
        Log.d(TAG, "decreasing lemonSize by 1")
        Log.d(TAG, "lemonSize before decreasing by 1 lemonSize = $lemonSize")
        lemonSize = lemonSize - 1
        Log.d(TAG, "lemonSize after decreasing by 1 lemonSize = $lemonSize")

        //lemonSize = 0//REMOVE once done with testing
        //Log.d(TAG, "lemonSizeHere = $lemonSize ** REMOVE")

        //If the lemonSize has reached 0, it has been juiced and the state should become DRINK
        if (lemonSize == 0) {
            lemonadeState = DRINK
            lemonSize = -1
            Log.d(TAG, "lemonadeState when lemonSize == 0 lemonadeState = $lemonadeState")
        }
    }
```

**LOGS:**

```
2022-06-16 15:37:50.847 11279-11362/com.example.lemonade W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to initialize 101010-2 format, error = EGL_SUCCESS
2022-06-16 15:37:54.501 11279-11279/com.example.lemonade D/MainActivity: lemonadeState at beginning of SELECT *should be SELECT* lemonadeState = select
2022-06-16 15:37:54.502 11279-11279/com.example.lemonade D/MainActivity:  setting lemonSize to 2 -> lemonSize = 2
2022-06-16 15:37:54.502 11279-11279/com.example.lemonade D/MainActivity:  setting squeezeCount to 0 -> squeezeCount = 0
2022-06-16 15:37:54.503 11279-11279/com.example.lemonade D/MainActivity: lemonadeState at bottom of SELECT *should be SQUEEZE* lemonadeState = squeeze
2022-06-16 15:38:11.862 11279-11279/com.example.lemonade D/MainActivity: at top of SQUEEZE *lemonSize should be 2* lemonSize = -1
2022-06-16 15:38:11.863 11279-11279/com.example.lemonade D/MainActivity: at top of SQUEEZE *lemonadeState should be SQUEEZE* lemonadeState = squeeze
2022-06-16 15:38:11.864 11279-11279/com.example.lemonade D/MainActivity: lemonSize before decreasing by 1 lemonSize = -1
2022-06-16 15:38:11.865 11279-11279/com.example.lemonade D/MainActivity: lemonSize after decreasing by 1 lemonSize = -2
```

Comment: I'm not seeing anything wrong with the code lemon size will pass from 2 to 1 to 0 to -1, did you expect something else

Comment: yes, see updated post with logs.

Comment: oh I understand now, I think that you are initializing the value of lemonSize inside the loop, try to initialize it outside the loop

Comment: i figured it out, I had a  private var lemonSize = -1 in MainActivity. And by calling val lemonSize = 2 im technically creating a new variable. also i should probably used var instead of val anyway :). This was resolved by changing val lemonSize = 2 to lemonSize = 2

Comment: Oh nice, I didn't notice it, good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a private var lemonSize = -1 in MainActivity. And by calling val lemonSize = 2 im technically creating a new variable. also i should probably used var instead of val anyway :). This was resolved by changing val lemonSize = 2 to lemonSize = 2